# Cómo verificar si un input,textarea etc está vacío

Tags: php, html, php7

Hice un sistema de comentarios, envía el comentario, hasta ahí todo bien, pero el único problema es aún que no haya nada en el textarea se envía el comentario en blanco y lo que quiero es que al intentar enviar un comentario vacío salga un mensaje de error y no se envíe (ej. No dejes campos vacíos).

```
    // Envíar comentario
    if(isset($_POST["_commentSubmit"])) {
        $message = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["_fullMessage"]);
        $message = strip_tags($message);
        $db->real_query("INSERT INTO profile_wall (page_id, poster_id, message, time) VALUES ('" . $_pageId . "', '" . USER_ID . "', '" . $message . "', '" . time() . "')");
    }

// Formulario
<form method='post'>
            <center>
            <textarea name="_fullMessage" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
            </center>
            <br />
            <div align='right'>
                <input class="btblack" type='submit' name='_commentSubmit' value='Comentar'>
            </div>
        </form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en PHP, perdonen por lo básico de este problema pero necesito alguna solución. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Yo haría dos cosas, ponerle un `required` al textarea y comprobar que el campo no esta vacio en php con esta condición. `if (!strlen(trim($_POST['_fullMessage']))) {  // Error  }`.

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar un

```
if (isset($_POST["_commentSubmit"])){ if(empty($_POST['_fullMessage'])){ echo "* agrega el campo vacio
"; } }
```